# Assert exception details with JestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception, jestjs

## Question

I set up the following Jest test to ensure an exception is thrown:

```js
it('can not rollback a step', async () => {
  await expect(app.service('rides').patch(ride._id, {
    currentStep: 1,
  })).rejects.toThrow(BadRequest);
});
```

How can I assert the exception content?

## Example

Considering this BadRequest error:

```
    BadRequest {
      type: 'FeathersError',
      name: 'BadRequest',
      message: 'invalid data',
      code: 400,
      className: 'bad-request',
      data: {},
      errors: [
        {
          message: 'currentStep must be greater than 1',
          path: [Array],
          type: 'array.min',
          context: [Object]
        }
      ],
```

I would like to check `errors[0].message` content, regardless the rest of the error object.

Answer (score 0):

you `catch` and then analyze. Don't forget `jest.assertions()` to ensure code really throws.

```
jest.assertions(1);
try {
  await app.service('rides').patch(ride._id, {
    currentStep: 1,
  });
} catch(e) {
  expect(e.errors[0].message).toEqual('abc');
}
```